# Do cremated remains contaminate with tumas mes?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, fire-burning

If a body is cremated, do the ashes transmit tumah as do other human remains, or does cremation render the body no longer tamei?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a matter of dispute in the [Mishna Oholos 2:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%91). Rabbi Eliezer says one quarter kav worth of ash does transmit impurity, whilst the Sages say it does not transmit impurity at all. Rambam ([Hilchos Tumas Meis 3:9-10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a103.htm#8)) rules like the Sages.