# Do cremated animal remains contaminate with Tumas Mes, Nevela or Sherets?

Tags: halacha-theory, death, animals, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

If I keep an urn at home containing the ashes of my deceased and cremated favourite pet, if I touch/carry the ashes does this make me *tamei* ?

Comment: For sherets no. I it's dessicated it's no more tame

Comment: There is no intrinsec tumas met for animals

Answer (score 3):

A dead Kosher animal would normally transmit *Tumas Neveila*, and a dead non Kosher animal would transmit *Tumas Beheima Temeia* (Rambam Hilchos Shaar Avos Hatuma 1,1-3)

The Rambam Hilchos Shaar Avos Hatuma 1,13 says that when the animal is dried up to the point that it cannot turn get its moisture back by soaking in warm  water, the animal no longer transmits tuma, **so ash of an animal does not transmit Tuma.**

> **בשר נבילה שיבש** אם יכול לשרות בפושרין מעת לעת לחזור לח וראוי לכלב מטמא ואם לאו טהור ואפילו באוכלין טמאין **אינו מטמא**

Comment: this is for flesh, what with atsamot?

Comment: @kouty Atzanot see here for when Atzamot- bones contract tuma https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79371/are-pig-bones-and-feather-from-non-kosher-animals-human-hair-human-dried-bone/86314#86314

Comment: What about Of and Sheretz?

Comment: @double  I think the Rambam quoted includes Ofe and sheretz as not contracting Tuma when dehydrated ואפילו באוכלין טמאין אינו מטמא

Comment: @yosefkorn I'm sure user15464 knows that's not correct and this Rambam is explicitly only about Nivlat Behema

Comment: @Doubleaa I'm not sure how you understand the Rambam,ochlin Tameiiin just means non kosher food whether sheretz or Ofe Tamei, the only thing not covered is nivlas Ofe tahor but it seems that the reason of not fit for consumption by a dog would apply in such a case to be considered noncontractable with tuma

Comment: @yosefkorn don't have time to explain to you now. Hopefully user15464 can when he gets back

Answer (score 2):

No.  Tumas meis is only for human corpses, and the accepted halacha is [it doesn't even apply to human ashes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27808/11532).

Comment: While true, a better answer would address other impurities too.